# Bootstrap 3 Popover: display on hover AND on click, aka. Pin a Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Making a popover appear with the **hover** trigger works fine.

Making a popover appear with the **click** trigger works fine.

Now, how do I go about making the popover appear when the triggering image is hovered over, but then if the user clicks on the image, cancel the hover and initiate a click toggle? In other words, hovering shows the popover and clicking 'pins' the popover.

The HTML is pretty standard:

```
<li>User<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" rel="popover" data-trigger="click" data-container="body" data-placement="auto left" data-content="Body Text" data-original-title="Title Text"></span></li>
```

And the popover initialization, even more boring:

```
$(function () { 
    $("[rel=popover]").popover();   
});
```

From what I have seen so far, it seems likely that the solution is a nice complex set of `popover('show')`, `popover('hide')`, and `popover('toggle')` calls, but my javascript / jQuery-foo is not up to the task.

**EDIT:**

Using the code provided by @hajpoj as a base, I added a function to listen to the `hidden.bs.popover` event to try to re-enable the mouseenter and mouseleave events after triggering the click event, but although it does make the 'hover' work again, it kills the click...

```
var $btn2 = $('#btn2');

    var enterShow = function() {
        $btn2.popover('show');
    };

    var exitHide = function() {
        $btn2.popover('hide');
    }

    $btn2.popover({trigger: 'manual'})
            .on('mouseenter', enterShow)
            .on('mouseleave', exitHide)
            .one('click', function() {
                   $btn2.off('mouseenter', enterShow)
                        .off('mouseleave', exitHide)
                        .on('click', function() {
                            $btn2.popover('toggle');
                        });
            });

$('#btn2').on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
  $btn2.on('mouseenter', enterShow)
       .on('mouseleave', exitHide)
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Edit:**

Heres an updated solutions based off your comment. It doesn't stay in a 'click' state but returns to the hover state.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/JJQS9/15/

html:

```
<a href="#" id="btn2" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A Title">Click to toggle popover</a>
```

js:

```
var $btn2 = $('#btn2');
$btn2.data('state', 'hover');

var enterShow = function () {
    if ($btn2.data('state') === 'hover') {
        $btn2.popover('show');
    }
};
var exitHide = function () {
    if ($btn2.data('state') === 'hover') {
        $btn2.popover('hide');
    }
};

var clickToggle = function () {
    if ($btn2.data('state') === 'hover') {
        $btn2.data('state', 'pinned');
    } else {
        $btn2.data('state', 'hover')
        $btn.popover('hover');
    }
};

$btn2.popover({trigger: 'manual'})
    .on('mouseenter', enterShow)
    .on('mouseleave', exitHide)
    .on('click', clickToggle);
```

---

**Old:**

I believe this is what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/JJQS9/1/

html:

```
<a href="#" id="btn2" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A Title">Click to toggle popover</a>
```

js:

```
var $btn2 = $('#btn2');

var enterShow = function() {
    $btn2.popover('show');
};

var exitHide = function() {
    $btn2.popover('hide');
}

$btn2.popover({trigger: 'manual'})
        .on('mouseenter', enterShow)
        .on('mouseleave', exitHide)
        .one('click', function() {
            $btn2.off('mouseenter', enterShow)
                    .off('mouseleave', exitHide)
                    .on('click', function() {
                        $btn2.popover('toggle');
                    });
        });
```

Basically you manually pop open/close the popover on the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, but once someone clicks on the popover for the first time, you remove those event handlers, and add a new handler on the `click` event that toggles the popover.

**Edit:** 
an alternative js code. simpler code, but there is a small visual blip when you use it:
http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/r3Ckt/1/

```
var $btn2 = $('#btn2');

$btn2.popover({trigger: 'hover'})
    .one('click', function() {
        $btn2.popover('destroy')
            .popover({ trigger: 'click'})
            .popover('show');
    });
```

Comment: The above code works great, except for one detail. Once you 'click' and pin the popover, and then 'click' to remove the popover, the mouseenter/mouseleave events no longer function. See the edit to the original question to see my attempt at re-enabling this functionality. It almost works...

Comment: Did you mean .on('click' instead of .one('click' ?

Comment: @hajpoj, I had a problem with the edited answer. The line `$btn.popover('hover');`  is incorrect. It should be  `$btn2.popover('show');` since it gives script error for `hover` in popover function.

Answer (score 8):

Very simple, add `hover` to `data-trigger` as follows:

```
<span rel="popover" data-trigger="hover click" data-container="body" data-placement="auto" data-content="Body Text"></span>
```

Comment: This does add both handlers but the click doesn't pin it. When you mouse-out after clicking to show it, it disappears.

Comment: @scipilot I tested it in bootstrap 4 and the click does pin it, even if you mouse-out

Comment: Interesting thanks @Alphacoder, I'm just migrating one site to BS4, may come in handy (I can't remember what I needed this for now though!).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a hybrid popover/tooltip that could give you the functionality that you are looking for both options, toggles on click and hover):

[Hybrid popover/tooltip fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikesi2/LswUw/)

HTML:

```
<button id="tip1" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title='this text!'>What's hidden?</button>
```

JS:

```
var $tip1 = $('#tip1');

$tip1.tooltip({trigger: 'hover'})
  .on('click', function() {
    $tip1.tooltip('toggle');
});
```

Comment: But the click doesn't pin it. When you mouse-out after clicking to show, it disappears.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the way I accomplished the hover/pin functionality using Bootstrap and JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var clicked = false;

    var onLeave = function() {
        if (!clicked) { $(this).popover('hide'); }
    };

    var onEnter = function () {
        if (!clicked) { $(this).popover('show'); }
    };

    var clickToggle = function() {
        if (clicked) { $(this).popover('hide'); }
        clicked = !clicked;
    }
    $('.popover-div-class').popover({ trigger: "manual"})
        .on('mouseenter', onEnter)
        .on('mouseleave', onLeave)
        .on('click', clickToggle);
});
```

I'm not sure it'll work in all scenarios, but it worked in mine. Big shoutout to @hajpoj and @Trevor for the inspiration.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5m2ob3yf/ (Doesn't work yet, but you can get the gist).