# Bootstrap popover does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to toggle a popover when users hover their mouse in to a div. Is using popover with `div` possible or I am doing something wrong. My code:

```
<div class="grid-item content-text" data-toogle ="popover" data-content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" data-trigger="hover" id="intro">
    <h3> INTRO</h3>
    <p>Hover me</p>
</div>
```

I also ut these in $(document).ready() function:

```
  $(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  });
```

My js script is in order and i do have bootstrap.css at top of my `head` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" ></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/customScripts.js" ></script>
```

However, I think there is something wrong with my popover implementation. I failed even with just `data-trigger = "focus"`. I created a pen on codepen.io: http://codepen.io/ngp130895/pen/qZQJOJ

Comment: you need to add the css

Comment: set the trigger to manual and add a mouseenter and mouseleve event [here's an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18754902/3591300) I've seen previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it was not identifying to which `element` - `popover` was attached, for reasons unknown. But when I tried it with giving `classname` of the `div` it actually identified the `element`.

```
$(function() {
  $('.grid-item').popover();
})
```

**[`DEMO HERE`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/48pnzt2g/2/)**

> **Note** - I've also given width to `div` and specified `data-placement` attribute to place it properly. Since `div` `width` was *`100%`* by default, it will move `popover` to end and hence will not be visible on the screen. You need to play around with these attributes. Also, I've not seen anywhere, `popover` is used on `div`. Please go through few of their properties and suggestions mentioned in their **[`official site`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)**