# Boostrap popover trigger focus not working on SVG <g> tag

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have used SVG in my project, Inside SVG there is  tag used, on which I have called bootstrap popover which is working fine on data-trigger click and hover. But it is not working on data-trigger="focus".

Any help much appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

This might be answered through this question: [Bootstrap 3 Popover: display on hover AND on click, aka. Pin a Popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735180/bootstrap-3-popover-display-on-hover-and-on-click-aka-pin-a-popover)

It's hard to tell without code example.

Comment: Hello Here is the link of codepen.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MoKJJX?editors=1010

Please resize codepen sidebar if its not worked