# Can I have hover and click in Bootstrap JS Popover?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using Bootstrap Popover plugin: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover.asp

I've been asked to make both hover and click works. But I can't set two values in the `data-trigger` attribute.

```
<a tabindex="0" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="popover"
    data-placement="top" title="Click and Hover!"
    data-content="<b> Click and Hover works! </b>" data-html="true">
    Click or hover here
</a>
```

How do I make both the Hover / Click work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 Popover: display on hover AND on click, aka. Pin a Popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735180/bootstrap-3-popover-display-on-hover-and-on-click-aka-pin-a-popover)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can specify multiple triggers simply by separate them by a space like this :

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header"
   data-trigger="click hover"
   data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>
```